# VBA and GMail through a corporate login portal

Tags: excel, email, vba

I have been trying to figure this out, but I cannot. I'm working on a VBA project for a manufacturing setting, where forklift drivers need be able to directly email updated lists of material movements to clerks who document them in a new database system.

The idea is that there is a set of hard-coded email addresses in a Module and one click sends the spreadsheet directly to the email after the driver selects the clerk on duty in the particular shift.

The utility for drivers to pick the clerk on the shift is easy enough, the following rolls through 5 different clerks, scattered on various shifts, but there is little point in repeating the code:

```
Private Sub cboClerk_Change()

With UserForm1.cboClerk

    If .ListIndex = 0 Then 'listindex goes from 0 to 4

        UserForm1.lblEmail = "fname.lname@company.com"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1") = UserForm1.lblEmail
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "Clerk on duty: First, Last"


    End If

end with
```

The next part is causing me issues. There are a number of examples for accessing gmail from VBA that I've tried adapting, and this was the most promising solution that I was able to locate, and of which I claim no authorship whatsoever:

```
Sub ActivateGmail()


Dim newMail As CDO.Message

Set newMail = New CDO.Message

'enable SSL authentication

newMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

'make SMTP authenticaion Enabled = true (1)

newMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

'set the SMTP server and port details
'to get these details you can get on the settings page of your Gmail account

newMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

newMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 2

newMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 587


'set your credentials of your Gmail account

newMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "firstandlast@company.com"

newMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypassword"

'update the configuration fields
newMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

'set all email properties

With newMail

    .Subject = "Test mail"
    .From = "firstandlast@company.com"
    .To = "firstandlast@company.com"
    .TextBody = "I gots it!"
End With

newMail.Send
MsgBox ("Mail has been sent")

'set the newMail variable to nothing

Set newMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

There is a corporate portal with a global ID and password that includes access to gmail, which I believe prevents me from referring to gmail directly with the above solution. Attempting to login from gmail.com redirects to the corporate login page, which has its own login credentials. I've temporarily resorted to the following:

```
Sub try6()

ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="http://www.gmail.com", NewWindow:=True

End Sub
```

...which works should the driver be luckily already logged into gmail, but it would still necessitate the manual labour of sending an email. Because of lacklustre wifi at the factory I work in, logins time out and this is not a sufficient solution. As such, I am wondering how to incorporate a corporate login portal as a part of a VBA gmail solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So have you succeeded with CDO? What are exact issues, did you get any errors? Have you allowed [access to less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)?

Comment: Yes. I enabled that option in gmail. The error i got hangs up at the Send line, and it is apparently due to bad credentials. Ergo, the company uses gmail, but it is a different domain, alongside the login portal, which prevents a direct connection to gmail. I can detail the error messages later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Try `newMail.Configuration.Load -1` right after the line `Set newMail = New CDO.Message`. Do you have a proxy, and if so is it necessary to enter proxy credentials for internet access?

Comment: I don't need proxy credentials to access the Internet, but to access my email, I do, through that corporate portal. I tried your suggestion, but I get a Runtime 3749 error, telling me that the Fields update failed and to examine the Status property of individual field objects. I'll keep looking...

Comment: I'm exploring an angle that because a corporate login is required before getting to gmail, the mail server might have a different name than smtp.gmail.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbelievable. I think I figured it out.

First, credit to the author on this page for the code that looks similar to the first post: http://www.codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=send-email-access-vba-cdo

To wit:

```
Public Sub sendmail()

Dim mail As CDO.Message
Dim config As CDO.Configuration

Set mail = CreateObject("CDO.message")
Set config = CreateObject("Cdo.configuration")

config.Fields(cdoSendUsingMethod).Value = cdoSendUsingPort
config.Fields(cdoSMTPServer).Value = "aspmx.l.google.com"
config.Fields(cdoSMTPServerPort).Value = 25 '25
config.Fields(cdoSMTPAuthenticate).Value = cdoBasic  'cdoNTLM  'cdoBasic 'cdoNTLM
config.Fields(cdoSendUserName).Value = "fname.lname@company.com" 'domain is not gmail
config.Fields(cdoSendPassword).Value = "mypassword"
config.Fields.Update

Set mail.Configuration = config

With mail

    .To = "fname.lname@company.com"
    .From = "fname.lname@company.com"
    .Subject = "Hello"
    .TextBody = "Plain email with CDO"

    '.addattachment "Path"

    .Send

End With

Set config = Nothing
Set mail = Nothing

End Sub
```

What cracked the problem was replacing `smtp.gmail.com` with `aspmx.l.google.com`. What it does is it bypasses the corporate login portal entirely and can send an email from the driver's account without him even needing to be logged into it. That's even better than I was hoping for.

Authentication must not be 465 or 587, which are Google's outgoing ports, because the `Config.fields.update`line will throw an error. It must be either `cdoBasic` or `cdoNTLM`, both of which work in sending an email. I'm not aware of any additional options than these, currently.

SMTPServerPort should (must?) be 25.

Hopefully this works for anyone else facing similar issues.